# WPF: put an icon on a radWindow programatically

Tags: wpf, image, telerik, icons, radwindow

I want to put an icon on the top left of a radWindow programatically

my code is like this

> ```
>     RadWindow radWindow = new RadWindow();
> radWindow.Header = "The header";
> radWindow.Icon = new Image()
>    {
>    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../ressources/enregistrer.png", UriKind.Relative))
>    };
> radWindow.Show();
> ```

but the icon dont show up

does anyone have an idea ?

**EDIT**

This is the architecture on my project:
 The file from where the above code is taken is circled in red
 The ressource file is circled in green

[image]

Comment: Is there any error? I suspect relative path for image is not getting resolved. Can you tell the hierarchy where your image resides in project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why my solution above did not work but I found a workaround like this

```
RadWindow radWindow = new RadWindow();
radWindow.Header = "The header";
radWindow.Icon = new Image()
{
                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ressources/enregistrer.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    }
 radWindow.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<telerik:RadWindow.Icon>
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/ressources/enregistrer.png" Height="18"/>
</telerik:RadWindow.Icon>

// this seems to work.  You will need to provide a size.
```